# Not able to display fetch data in react native

Tags: css, react-native, expo

am stuck with problem , am not able to display fetch API data on my screen ,can anyone tell me how to display data, please try to fix my code, if you have any queries please free feel to ask.

> am using nytimes api for fetching data

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
// import { Card, Title, Paragraph } from 'react-native-paper';
import { Searchbar } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function Home() {
  const [searchquery, setSearchquery] = React.useState();
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getMovies = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/current/hardcover-fiction.json?api-key=9OTXA7aqliGSkwHKCACiw0SLkmfzMB6g`
      );
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  }, []);

  return (
    <View>
      <Searchbar
        placeholder="Search Books"
        onChangeText={(query) => setSearchquery(query)}
        value={searchquery}
        style={{ marginTop: 30, marginHorizontal: 10 }}
      />
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Text style={styles.customText}> {item.json}</Text>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  customText: {
    padding: 10,
    marginTop: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

Comment: You should not post your API keys on public forums

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You shouldn't post your private API keys in a public forum.

Now coming to your problem, You are supposed to give `FlatList` an `Array` to loop over. The `FlatList` component will loop over each item in your array and you can display them using the `renderItem`. A quick look at your API indicates that the API response you are getting is an `Object`, not an `Array`.

You probably want to loop over `books` array in your `FlatList`. Change your `getMovies` function to,

```js
const getMovies = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/current/hardcover-fiction.json?api-key=9OTXA7aqliGSkwHKCACiw0SLkmfzMB6g`
    );
    const json = await response.json();
    setData(json.results.books); // changed json to the specific key in your api response.
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

and in your `FlatList`, you can use,

```js
<FlatList
  data={data}
  keyExtractor={(item) => item.book_uri}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <Text style={styles.customText}>{item.title}</Text> // to display title.. like this map all your data based on the key received in api response.
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
<FlatList
  data={data}
  keyExtractor={(item) => id}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <Text style={styles.customText}> {item.json}</Text>}
/>
```

Use `id.toString()` if id is not a string.